# Process and record types

Tags: record-type, sales-process

We have process in salesforce.
1. Sales Process - Opportunity
2. Support Process - Case
3. Solution Process - Solution
4. Lead Process - Lead

Now we have record types and each record type must be associated with one Process.

Question is why Standard pick list values (Opportunity Stage, Lead Status, Case Status, Solution Status) not available for Editing Pick list value based on record type even other pick list values are available.

I just wanted to know the reason, I have seen many blogs , salesforce documentation but still not clear. Why salesforce does not allow these values in to Available Pick list values for Editing Section.

Thanks 
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage on opportunity and Status on Case for example are desgined by Salesforce to ensure the an opportunity or case functionality meets standard CRM features.
In accordance, a SF opportunity cannot be created without assigning a stage, that is like other picklists stage cannot be set to a --None-- value.
Similarly a case status picklist must contain a valid "Closed" type picklist value(for any record type), Salesforce altogether has a functionality built for closing a case through "Close case" button.
So support these standard features, wherever required Salesforce has built processes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking, why is Opportunity.Stagename treated differently from other picklists that can be customized by recordType?

The answer is this is by design in SFDC (and goes back a long ways).

A good reference is the online Help /pdfs/en/salesforce_busprocess_cheatsheet.pdf

The Sales process, which defines the Opportunity.Stagename picklist values, can map to multiple record types (see the setup for recordtype) - thus achieving the same effect as you desire but through a different UI configuration path.

The same applies for Lead, Support, and Solution processes

Comment: I still dint get exact answer, is there no one who can answer this question? Chart sheet also explaining same thing, but same can be achieve from record type pick list available values if available.

Comment: Vijay -- I suggest you post an Idea to decouple maintenance of stagename picklists from sales processes

Comment: On a very lighter note - I see this is kind of over engineering! I too got this question for myself then thought about how this is going to get benefit to me. All the process are designed as it is. I would go with "it is as per design" :)

Answer (score 1):

the reason 'stage' is not available in record types is because opportunity stage is strictly treated as part of the 'sales process' in SFDC. A record type has access to 'stage' indirectly - only by associating to a specific 'sales process'. Makes sense? This documentation should further help in understanding that association between sales processes, record types and with page layouts.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrhlTTPGmjY

Answer (score 0):

As a "Best Practice", one doesn't want to hard code Record Types into their pages, triggers or classes. If Record Types were included in a pick list, that's essentially what you'd be doing. I think that's the gist of your question as I understand it. I.E. select a Record Type from a drop down --> then get a dependent picklist?

Your page layout should generally make that unnecessary. Page layouts can be created according to Record Type so a different page layout appears depending on which Record Type a particular record is. If the things that differentiate between the types of records you have by Record Type aren't distinguishable by Page Layout, then perhaps you may not be using Record Types wisely OR you may want to implement Object/Global Actions according to Record Type to achieve what you desire.

As with many things Salesforce, very often there's more than one way to accomplish what you desire.

Comment: Not really - Just go to Setup-> Customize -> Opportunity -> Salesforce Process. Why this sales Process we should create? Why Stage pick list is not available when click on any record type like setup->Customize -> Opportunity -> Record Types-> Click any record type -> you will find list of pick list values but stage will not be available?